# Clear local storage but exempt certain values.

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to clear window.localStorage i.e `window.localStorage.clear();` but exempt certain key/value pairs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but you can save the values of what you want in a variable and then clear the `localStorage`  and then add the items stored in the variable to it again.

Example:

```
var myItem = localStorage.getItem('key');
localStorage.clear();
localStorage.setItem('key',myItem);
```

Comment: This was pretty much what I was planning on doing but wanted to see if there was a generally accepted way, seems like this is it!

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

```
for( var k in window.localStorage) {
   if( k == "key1" || k == "key2") continue;
   // use your preferred method there - maybe an array of keys to exclude?

   delete window.localStorage[k];
}
```

Comment: I looked at this way first; turns out the localStorage spec doesn't include the enumeration of for/in. Older versions of FireFox (at the very least) barf (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5410884/444991).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this manually;

```
function clearLocalStorage(exclude) {
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        var key = localStorage.key(i);

        if (exclude.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've purposefully taken the long winded approach of iterating over the length of `localStorage` and retrieving the matching key, rather than simply using `for/in`, as `for/in` of `localStorage` key's isn't specified in the spec. Older versions of FireFox barf when you `for/in`. I'm not sure on later versions ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410884/444991)).

`exclude` is expected to be an array of keys you wish to exclude from being deleted;

```
clearLocalStorage(["foo", "bar"]);
```