# Using localstorage.clear() but exclude 1 item

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a lot of items in localstorage, and I want to clear them all...except 1 item, we'll call it "X".

Is there a way to call localstorage.clear() but exclude X?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Store the value you'd like to keep in another variable, then use `localStorage.clear()`

**Example:**

```
var myItem = localStorage.getItem('key');
localStorage.clear();
localStorage.setItem('key',myItem);
```

Example was taken from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113655/clear-local-storage-but-exempt-certain-values).

Comment: ... and of course add the variable back to the localStorage once you've cleared it.

Comment: Thank you! Good idea, quality post.